# Free implementation in scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz, free-monad

The Free implementation in Haskell is:

```
data Free f a =
Pure a
| Free (f (Free f a))
```

whereas, the implementation in Scalaz is:

```
sealed abstract class Free[S[_], A]

private case class Return[S[_], A](a: A) extends Free[S, A]
private case class Suspend[S[_], A](a: S[A]) extends Free[S, A]
private case class Gosub[S[_], B, C](a: Free[S, C], f: C => Free[S, B]) extends Free[S, B]
```

why isn't the scalaz implementation similar to Haskell, like:

```
sealed trait Free[F[_],A]
case class Return[F[_],A](a: A) extends Free[F,A]
case class GoSub[F[_],A](s: F[Free[F,A]]) extends Free[F,A]
```

Are these both implementations isomorphic?

Comment: How would you create a `Free[F, A]` given an `F[A]` using the second Scala implementation ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens that is very well possible when `F` is a `Functor`. The problem with such representation is that it leads to stack-safety issues.

Comment: @TomasMikula. Ok I see `GoSub[F, A](F.map(fa)(Return[F, A](_)))`, thanks !

Answer (score 7):

The translation of that Haskell code to Scala would be

```
sealed abstract class Free[S[_], A]

case class Return[S[_], A](a: A) extends Free[S, A]
case class Suspend[S[_], A](a: S[Free[S, A]]) extends Free[S, A]
```

The Haskell implementation doesn't need the `Gosub` case thanks to lazy evaluation. This representation would work in Scala as well, but it would lead to stack-overflow problems due to (strict evaluation and) lack of tail-call elimination. To make it stack-safe, we represent `flatMap` lazily, as `Gosub` (I think `FlatMap` would be a better name):

```
case class Gosub[S[_], B, C](a: Free[S, C], f: C => Free[S, B]) extends Free[S, B]
```

As a bonus, the introduction of `Gosub` allows us to simplify `Suspend` to

```
case class Suspend[S[_], A](a: S[A]) extends Free[S, A]
```

because we don't need to do `flatMap`s by mapping over the content of `S[_]` anymore—we represent `flatMap`s explicitly as `Gosub`s.

As a consequence, this resulting representation, unlike the Haskell representation, allows us to do everything one wants to do with `Free` without ever requiring `Functor[S]`. So we don't even need to mess with the "Coyoneda trick" when our `S` is not a `Functor`.