# Free Monads fromulation

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

As far as I understand Free construction allows lifting any Functor to Monad. When I work with Cats library I can lift this ADT to monad even without providing functor instance, how it is possible?

```
sealed trait DataA[A]

case class GetData(id: String) extends DataA[String]

case class SaveData(d: String) extends DataA[Unit]
```

Also in traditional (simple) approach when Free is defined by

```
trait Free[F[_], A]

final case class Pure[F[_], A](a: A) extends Free[F, A]

final case class Suspend[F[_], A](a: F[Free[F, A]]) extends Free[F, A]
```

I would have to encode my ADT with continuation:

```
sealed trait DataA[A]

case class GetData(id: String, cont: A) extends DataA[A]

case class SaveData(d: String, cont: A) extends DataA[A]
```

When I am using Cats I don't have to provide the cont parameter, why?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742360/free-implementation-in-scalaz/37755405#37755405). TL;DR: with the `cats` representation, `flatMap`s on the free monad don't need to be implemented via `map`-ping over the underlying functor, thus functor is not required at all.

Comment: Does it mean cats representation is strictly better than traditional haskell representation? I can't see any drawbacks.

Comment: I would say so, yes. Another nice property of that representation is that it is still useful after [taking away the `Pure` constructor](https://github.com/TomasMikula/freebind) (just like it makes sense to talk about a monad without the `pure` operation). OTOH, if you took away `Pure` from the traditional representation, you wouldn't even be able to implement `liftF`.

Comment: I just read Oleg Kiselyov Reflection without Remorse paper. They show how to get read of O(n^2) problem with left associative bind. It seams the same problem in CATS is solved by adding FlatMapped case to Free. I don't see any relation between these 2 solutions, are they completely different techniques? Adding the FlatMapped seems much easier.

Comment: I skimmed through the paper and the two techniques are similar in that they both represent `bind` (a.k.a. `flatMap`) more explicitly. The type-aligned sequence of Kleisli arrows used in the paper to represent a sequence of `bind`s gives more reflection than `FlatMapped`, though I'm not sure if that extra reflection is of any use (in the case of free monad, that is; the paper doesn't mention a use case where that would be beneficial).

Comment: On the other hand, the representation in the paper still conflates cats' `Suspend` and `FlatMapped` in one constructor, thus it still requires a `Functor`. See also [Freer monad](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/free-monad.html#freer), which is more like `Free` in `scalaz` and `cats` and doesn't require a functor.

Comment: It is, of course, possible to combine the two techniques and represent `FlatMapped` in `cats` as a type-aligned sequence of Kleislis. I was myself tempted to do so (I have a handy type-aligned sequence `FreeCompose` in [`type-aligned`](https://github.com/TomasMikula/type-aligned)), but then again, didn't see any added benefit to it.

Comment: Reading the paper, it is funny to notice how in Haskell people use a "clever" trick like `Suspend (f (Free f a))`, because they can afford it thanks to laziness and no stack-overflow issues. Then they observe it performs poorly so they use another "clever" trick like the `Codensity` monad (again, they can afford it because arbitrary function compositions don't cause stack overflow). But still, the trick doesn't quite cut it so finally they come up with a representation very similar to what one would have to do in a strict language from the start.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I need to study it more. I am amazed by the fact that cats representation doesn't need Functor for ADT. Do you have intuition why this is true?

Comment: I tried that in my very first comment above. To have a monad, you need to implement `pure` and `flatMap` on `Free`. In both representations, `pure` is represented directly. To implement `flatMap` on the original representation one needs to `map` over `F`, thus `F` has to be a Functor. In `cats` the `flatMap` operation is represented directly, thus no `Functor[F]` is needed.